# Cant replace \n by \\n in a string in typescript?

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I was trying to replace `\n` by `\\n` in a string in typescript. As i wanted to replace all occurrences, the best option was to use a regex expression.
suppose

```
let str="\n\nSimply tap or right click on these links";
str.replace(new RegExp('\n','gi'), '\\n');
```

But this does not work. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Use `str = str.replaceAll('\n', '\\\\n')`

Comment: "But this does not work. Can someone explain why?" Because **strings are immutable** in JavaScript.

Comment: You should replace with '\\\n'